# Chrome doesn't stop javascript in 'drag' event

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

So, Chrome devtools is not stopping javascript execution in 'drag' events, is this normal?

It brings up the shaded overlay on the page and says that stopped at the break point but the javascript calls to the drag function continue for as long as you continue to drag the element, making it very difficult to debug the first call to the function.

Here is an example of it in action

```js
 var ex = false;

  function onDrag () {
    debugger; //It doesn't stop javascript execution!
    console.log(ex);
    ex = true;
  }

  document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('drag', onDrag);
```

```css
    div {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: orange;
    }
```

```html
<div draggable="true">Open chrome devtools and DRAG ME</div>
```

```
 var ex = false;

  function onDrag () {
    debugger; //It doesn't stop javascript execution!
    console.log(ex);
    ex = true;
  }

  document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('drag', onDrag);
```

Comment: That's a bug, thanks. I've filed it on your behalf, feel free to star it: [crbug.com/587560](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587560)